# Related to ISKCON: Why sanyasins are so less in ISKCON Comparatively?

Tags: iskcon

Two Questions Related to Iskcon:

1-  Why female sanyasins/full time devotees are so less in ISKCON Comparatively ?

2-  Why males address to each other `PRABHU` there ?